# Shoreline identification using ERDAS 2011

Tags: remote-sensing, erdas-imagine

How can we separate shoreline from shallow water sea and land area in a LISS 3 image using ERDAS 2011 software?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a user of ERDAS software, but i'm wondering if you could use any of [these](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/shorelines/shorelines.html) datasets to help you distinguish particular features in the coastal environment you're working on?

I've found the GSHHG dataset a useful tool in the past.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options for land classification using Erdas. Since LISS3 imagery has two IR bands, you will be able to see good discrimination of water and land/vegetation.  There are two major groups of land classification: pixel-based and object-oriented classification.  For pixel-based classification methods, try using supervised maximum likelihood classification or ISODATA unsupervised classification--each are available in the Raster tab.  Erdas Imagine also has a module for object-oriented classification called Erdas Imagine "Objective".  I should note there is a steeper learning curve for the object-oriented classification.  Either way, you should have good luck differentiating water and land with your imagery using any of these methods of land classification.